# Strapi response mongodb relations field wrong

Tags: strapi

When calling a custom content type that has a relation many to many with users collection is giving me into the likes array a splitted user id who liked it. I can see into the array each record for each user id number.

I've setup everything from the UI. created a many to many relation field into users collection with studios and updated via strapi admin the records.

`"users": [
            {
                "confirmed": false,
                "blocked": false,
                "likes": [
                    {
                        "0": "5",
                        "1": "d",
                        "2": "8",
                        "3": "d",
                        "4": "1",
                        "5": "c",
                        "6": "4",
                        "7": "3",
                        "8": "1",
                        "9": "9",
                        "10": "0",
                        "11": "8",
                        "12": "5",
                        "13": "0",
                        "14": "6",
                        "15": "b",
                        "16": "c",
                        "17": "8",
                        "18": "3",
                        "19": "1",
                        "20": "4",
                        "21": "e",
                        "22": "d",
                        "23": "0"
                    }
                ],`

I would see the likes having the full id for the user who liked it and not as now one entry for each number into the id.

Comment: Can you give me your strapi version please.
You mentioned the studio. And the studio is available for the v1 of strapi.
We are in 3.0.0-beta.16.6 right now. I suggest you to use the last version of Strapi.
To use the last version, I suggest you to check this link https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/getting-started/quick-start.html#_1-install-strapi-and-create-a-new-project

Comment: with strapi version it says 3.0.0-beta.14, with yarn strapi -v 3.0.0-next.24.
btw on the admin dashboard in the bottom it says Strapi v3.0.0-beta.16.6 and also in the package dependencies i see the same Strapi v3.0.0-beta.16.6.

P.S. studio it is just a name for a collection.

Comment: Can you create a Gist of the request you did to create the relation please.